# function which gets another function as argument in SML

Tags: sml, ml

Consider function `g` gets `integer` and returns true if the `integer` is bigger than some random const positive value that was decided before, otherwise false.

I would like to write a function `f` in SML which gets the function `g` as argument. this function `f` should return this random const positive value that was decided before.

Algorithm (In some other language, C or something):

```
 int f(int num) {
     int num = 1;
     while(!g(num)) {
         num++;
     }
     return num;
 }
```

Now this is what I tried in SML:

```
fun f g = 
let
    val num = 1;
in
    while !(g num) do (
        val num = num + 1;
    );
    num
end;
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your C code is supposed to say `int f(bool (*g)(int)) {...`, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
val num = num + 1;
```

First of all `val` is only allowed at the top level or inside a `let`. Secondly it defines a new variable. So in your C code, it'd be equivalent to:

```
int num = num + 1;
```

And not:

```
num = num + 1;
```

In other words, it creates a new variable rather than modifying the existing one, which doesn't help you here.

So the natural follow-up question would be how you do `num = num + 1`. And the most direct answer is: you don't. All variables in SML are immutable, so you can't re-assign variables. However you can work around this by using `ref`s, which are mutable.

However the proper way to do this in SML is to not use `while` loops or re-assignments at all and instead use recursion.

Comment: How should I use recursion here?

Answer (score 1):

As sepp2k explained, your problem has nothing to do with the passing of `g` but how you try to define a loop. Here is one way to implement it using recursion, which is what you normally do in ML:

```
fun f' g n = if g n then n else f' g (n + 1)
fun f g = f' g 1
```

Or if you want to keep the auxiliary function local:

```
fun f g =
  let fun loop n = if g n then n else loop (n + 1)
  in loop 1 end
```

Comment: Thank you! how do you test it? `val x = f g ` something?

Comment: For example, `val x = f (fn n => n*n = 256)` will find you the square root of 256.